# Generate a PDF with form fields from an Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I have an excel sheet, that I with a VBA code, can convert to a PDF page/file.
My question is:
It is possible to select an area/cell on the excel sheet to be a "form field" (by VBA) and then generate the pdf, to then be able to open this pdf and fill in this form field, with the data I want and save it.
If yes, How?

Or do I need to pull the data I want from the excel sheet, and then use VBA to generate the PDF and then with Adobe Acrobat Pro, add then form fields I want other to be able to fill out?

Answer (score 0):

From Excel's native VBA you can only save the workbook (or parts of it) as a PDF. Saving as a PDF does not include any features that are only available in Acrobat Pro.

Building fillable forms is such a feature that is not available by saving and Excel workbook as a PDF. You will need to use Acrobat Pro for that.

Comment: Hi.. Ok hmm
Then I will look on Python, so I can use a script after the Excel/VBA to PDF, to add the Form field's, it's the same place, but for 20+ pdf files.
Thx Teylyn